# Return struct element from vector c++

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, stl, return-value

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to return a struct from a vector of structs by using 2 search criteria.

The function `find_city` is returning me everything from the defined range, regardless of whether it exists inside the vector of struct.

Here's my code:

```
struct cityLoc
{
    int hRange;
    int vRange;
    int cityCode;
    string cityName;
};

vector<cityLoc> cl1;

// the vector has already been preloaded with data

// function to return my struct from the vector
cityLoc find_city(int hRange, int vRange)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cl1.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((cl1[i].hRange = hRange) && (cl1[i].vRange = vRange))
        {
            return cl1[i];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++)
        {
            cityLoc this_city;
            this_city = find_city(i, j);
            cout << this_city.hRange << ", " << this_city.vRange << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, aside from this question, I was previously looking into `std::find_if` and didn't understand it. If I have the following code, what is the output? How do I modify it such that it returns a struct?

```
auto it = find_if(cl1.begin(), cl1.end(), [](cityLoc& cl) { return cl.hRange == 1; } );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug here:

```
    if ((cl1[i].hRange = hRange) && (cl1[i].vRange = vRange))
```

Those `=` are assignments, not comparisons!  Please enable compiler warnings and you won't be hurt by such obvious typos in future.

Comment: Thanks!! I have to use ubuntu as directed by my teacher so its hard to debug at times! But right now its printing multiple of the same range. Do I have to do anything else in order to prevent the function from returning a struct with value if there is no struct matching the search criteria?

Comment: Ubuntu has nothing to do with it, simply enable compiler warnings.  For example if you run `g++ foo.cpp`, you should instead run `g++ -Wall -Werror foo.cpp` to make the compiler stop when it sees broken code, rather than trudging on with a broken program.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) will return the iterator to the found struct entry if it is successful, `std::vector::end()` otherwise. So, you should first validate the returning iterator if it is valid or not.

For example:

```
auto it = std::find_if( cl1.begin(), cl1.end(),
                        [](const cityLoc& cl) { return cl.hRange == 1; } );

if ( it == cl1.end() )
{
    // ERROR: Not found! Return error code etc.
    return -1;
}

// And, if found, process it here...

std::cout << it->hRange << '\n';
std::cout << it->vRange << '\n';
```

The criteria (predicate) part in `std::find_if` is a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! I've been looking through multiple posts and still didn't understand what did 'it' return. This clarifies it!!

Comment: @Bao: You are welcome! You ought to first go through the standard reference before looking at other blog posts etc. C++ reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/) is the best place to start. Always.